# Can we fill color for countries in google_maps_flutter?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, maps

I'm implementing the google_maps_flutter plugin in my flutter app and stucked in highlighting the country for example India by red color, Australia by blue etc. I went throught geoJson but not sure how to implement it in flutter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21):

After spending 4 days in looking into map stuff and it's features I got most easy and feasible solution for filling any country, state, continent in flutter.
We can get the geoJson data of any region from [here](https://geojson-maps.ash.ms/)

Extract the latLong co-ordinates of that region and draw a polygon based on it.

Following is the code for filling India with colour.

**GeoJson.dart**

```
class GeoJson
{
 static const List IN = [
   [77.83745079947457,35.494009507787766],[78.91226891471322,34.32193634697579],
   [78.81108646028574,33.50619802503242],[79.20889163606857,32.994394639613716],
   [79.17612877799553,32.48377981213771],[78.45844648632601,32.61816437431273],
   [78.73889448437401,31.515906073527063],[79.7213668151071,30.882714748654728],
   [81.11125613802932,30.183480943313402],[80.4767212259174,29.72986522065534],
   [80.08842451367627,28.79447011974014],[81.05720258985203,28.416095282499043],
   [81.99998742058497,27.925479234319994],[83.30424889519955,27.36450572357556],
   [84.6750179381738,27.234901231387536],[85.25177859898338,26.72619843190634],
   [86.02439293817918,26.63098460540857],[87.22747195836628,26.397898057556077],
   [88.06023766474982,26.41461538340249],[88.17480431514092,26.81040517832595],
   [88.04313276566123,27.445818589786825],[88.12044070836987,27.876541652939594],
   [88.73032596227856,28.086864732367516],[88.81424848832054,27.29931590423936],
   [88.83564253128938,27.098966376243762],[89.74452762243884,26.719402981059957],
   [90.37327477413407,26.87572418874288],[91.21751264848643,26.808648179628022],
   [92.03348351437509,26.83831045176356],[92.10371178585973,27.452614040633208],
   [91.69665652869668,27.77174184825166],[92.50311893104364,27.89687632904645],
   [93.41334760943268,28.640629380807226],[94.56599043170294,29.277438055939985],
   [95.40480228066464,29.03171662039213],[96.11767866413103,29.452802028922466],
   [96.58659061074749,28.830979519154344],[96.24883344928779,28.41103099213444],
   [97.32711388549004,28.26158274994634],[97.40256147663612,27.88253611908544],
   [97.0519885599681,27.69905894623315],[97.1339990580153,27.083773505149964],
   [96.41936567585097,27.264589341739224],[95.12476769407496,26.5735720891323],
   [95.1551534362626,26.001307277932085],[94.60324913938538,25.162495428970402],
   [94.55265791217164,24.675238348890332],[94.10674197792505,23.85074087167348],
   [93.3251876159428,24.078556423432204],[93.28632693885928,23.043658352139005],
   [93.06029422401463,22.70311066333557],[93.16612755734836,22.278459580977103],
   [92.67272098182556,22.041238918541254],[92.14603478390681,23.627498684172593],
   [91.86992760617132,23.624346421802784],[91.70647505083211,22.985263983649183],
   [91.15896325069971,23.50352692310439],[91.46772993364367,24.072639471934792],
   [91.91509280799443,24.13041372323711],[92.37620161333481,24.976692816664965],
   [91.79959598182207,25.147431748957317],[90.8722107279121,25.132600612889547],
   [89.92069258012185,25.26974986419218],[89.83248091019962,25.96508209889548],
   [89.35509402868729,26.014407253518073],[88.56304935094977,26.44652558034272],
   [88.2097892598025,25.76806570078271],[88.93155398962308,25.238692328384776],
   [88.30637251175602,24.866079413344206],[88.08442223506242,24.501657212821925],
   [88.69994022009092,24.23371491138856],[88.52976972855377,23.631141872649163],
   [88.87631188350309,22.879146429937826],[89.03196129756623,22.055708319582976],
   [88.88876590368542,21.690588487224748],[88.20849734899521,21.703171698487807],
   [86.97570438024027,21.49556163175521],[87.03316857294887,20.743307806882413],
   [86.49935102737378,20.151638495356607],[85.0602657409097,19.4785788029711],
   [83.94100589390001,18.302009792549725],[83.18921715691785,17.67122142177898],
   [82.19279218946592,17.016636053937813],[82.19124189649719,16.556664130107848],
   [81.69271935417748,16.310219224507904],[80.79199913933014,15.951972357644491],
   [80.32489586784388,15.899184882058348],[80.02506920768644,15.136414903214147],
   [80.2332735533904,13.835770778859981],[80.28629357292186,13.006260687710833],
   [79.8625468281285,12.056215318240888],[79.85799930208682,10.35727509199711],
   [79.340511509116,10.30885427493962],[78.88534549348918,9.546135972527722],
   [79.18971967968828,9.216543687370148],[78.2779407083305,8.933046779816934],
   [77.94116539908435,8.252959092639742],[77.53989790233794,7.965534776232333],
   [76.59297895702167,8.89927623131419],[76.13006147655108,10.299630031775521],
   [75.74646731964849,11.308250637248307],[75.39610110870957,11.781245022015824],
   [74.86481570831681,12.741935736537897],[74.61671715688354,13.99258291264968],
   [74.44385949086723,14.617221787977696],[73.5341992532334,15.99065216721496],
   [73.11990929554943,17.928570054592498],[72.82090945830865,19.208233547436166],
   [72.8244751321368,20.419503282141534],[72.6305334817454,21.356009426351008],
   [71.17527347197395,20.757441311114235],[70.4704586119451,20.877330634031384],
   [69.16413008003883,22.0892980005727],[69.64492760608239,22.450774644454338],
   [69.34959679553435,22.84317963306269],[68.1766451353734,23.69196503345671],
   [68.84259931831878,24.35913361256094],[71.04324018746823,24.3565239527302],
   [70.84469933460284,25.21510203704352],[70.28287316272558,25.72222870533983],
   [70.16892662952202,26.491871649678842],[69.51439293811312,26.940965684511372],
   [70.61649620960193,27.989196275335868],[71.77766564320032,27.913180243434525],
   [72.8237516620847,28.961591701772054],[73.45063846221743,29.97641347911987],
   [74.42138024282026,30.979814764931177],[74.40592898956501,31.69263947196528],
   [75.25864179881322,32.2711054550405],[74.45155927927871,32.7648996038055],
   [74.10429365427734,33.44147329358685],[73.74994835805195,34.31769887952785],
   [74.24020267120497,34.74888703057125],[75.75706098826834,34.50492259372132],
   [76.87172163280403,34.65354401299274],[77.83745079947457,35.494009507787766]];
}
```

**main.dart**

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    addPoints();
    List< Polygon > addPolygon = [
      Polygon(
        polygonId: PolygonId( 'India' ),
        points: point,
        consumeTapEvents: true,
        strokeColor: Colors.grey,
        strokeWidth: 1,
        fillColor: Colors.redAccent,
      ),
    ];
    polygon.addAll( addPolygon );

    super.initState();
  }

void addPoints()
 {
   for( var i=0 ; i < GeoJson.IN.length ; i++ )
   {
     var ltlng= LatLng( GeoJson.IN[ i ][ 1 ], GeoJson.IN[ i ][ 0 ] );
     point.add( ltlng );
   }
 }

 void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller)
 {
   mapController = controller;
 }

Widget mapState()
 {
   return GoogleMap(
     onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
     initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
         target: _center,
         zoom: 0.0
     ),
     scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
     zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
     myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
     gestureRecognizers: Set()
       ..add( Factory<PanGestureRecognizer>(() => PanGestureRecognizer())),
     //markers: markers,
     polygons: polygon,
   );
 }
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: perfect answer!

Comment: Thank you @Monis

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wondering - here is the full main.dart code that can be copy & pasted in order to work. Make sure to add your API key for google maps under android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.

Lastly add the geojson.dart as described above.

```
    import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
    import 'geojson.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      // This widget is the root of your application.
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            // This is the theme of your application.
            //
            // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
            // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
            // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
            // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
            // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
            // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
            // is not restarted.
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            // This makes the visual density adapt to the platform that you run
            // the app on. For desktop platforms, the controls will be smaller and
            // closer together (more dense) than on mobile platforms.
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
          ),
          home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
    
    
      final String title;
    
      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }
    
    class _MyHomePageState extends State {
      Set polygon = new Set();
    
      List point = [];
    
    
      GoogleMapController mapController;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        addPoints();
        List addPolygon = [
          Polygon(
            polygonId: PolygonId( 'India' ),
            points: point,
            consumeTapEvents: true,
            strokeColor: Colors.grey,
            strokeWidth: 1,
            fillColor: Colors.redAccent,
          ),
        ];
        polygon.addAll( addPolygon );
    
        super.initState();
      }
    
      void addPoints()
      {
        for( var i=0 ; i (() => PanGestureRecognizer())),
          //markers: markers,
          polygons: polygon,
        );
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // TODO: implement build
        return mapState();
    
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Full Code (combination of two above answers):

```
main.dart:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:map_test/dist1.dart';

import 'dist2.dart';
import 'dist3.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: GoogleMapPage(),
    );
  }
}


class GoogleMapPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GoogleMapPageState createState() => _GoogleMapPageState();
}

class _GoogleMapPageState extends State<GoogleMapPage> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  Set<Polygon> polygon = new Set();

  @override
  void initState() {
    List<LatLng> distPoints = addPoints();
    List<Polygon> distPolygon = [
      Polygon(
        polygonId: PolygonId('dist'),
        points: distPoints,
        consumeTapEvents: true,
        strokeColor: Colors.grey,
        strokeWidth: 1,
        fillColor: Color(0xFFFF1744).withOpacity(0.4),
      ),
    ];
    polygon.addAll(distPolygon);
    super.initState();
  }

  addPoints() {
    List<LatLng> point = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < Dist.IN.length; i++) {
        var latLang = LatLng(Dist.IN[i][1], Dist.IN[i][0]);
        point.add(latLang);
    }
    return point;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: GoogleMap(
          onMapCreated: (controller) {
            _controller.complete(controller);
          },
          gestureRecognizers: Set()
            ..add(Factory<PanGestureRecognizer>(() => PanGestureRecognizer())),
          initialCameraPosition:
              CameraPosition(target: LatLng(35.697791, 51.379233), zoom: 10),
          polygons: polygon,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

dist.dart:

```
class Dist
{
  static const List IN = [
    [
      51.38412002338114,
      35.74300506579035
    ],
    [
      51.38461899807706,
      35.74429378340329
    ],
    [
      51.38539139045448,
      35.74586119929674
    ],
    [
      51.385842085388134,
      35.74709769765289
    ],
    [
      51.385986840855935,
      35.748299327291846
    ],
    [
      51.38606194270838,
      35.74984922500766
    ],
    [
      51.38611558688868,
      35.75121622959622
    ],
    [
      51.386255061757474,
      35.75327985415754
    ],
    [
      51.38629529489273,
      35.75416791679879
    ],
    [
      51.38644558241663,
      35.75496025810577
    ],
    [
      51.38672989657226,
      35.75584823692799
    ],
    [
      51.38709459317934,
      35.75661015192645
    ],
    [
      51.387958264482336,
      35.7582948306453
    ],
    [
      51.3882801295642,
      35.75890863741469
    ],
    [
      51.3885215283756,
      35.75957893821146
    ],
    [
      51.38860199464608,
      35.760101382236286
    ],
    [
      51.38866636766244,
      35.76085005382773
    ],
    [
      51.3884839774494,
      35.76201664711144
    ],
    [
      51.388237298039,
      35.76340091842053
    ],
    [
      51.387411093843184,
      35.76834565455968
    ],
    [
      51.38734135640877,
      35.76914654540792
    ],
    [
      51.387384271753035,
      35.76987778264077
    ],
    [
      51.38751301778577,
      35.77062637041319
    ],
    [
      51.38772759450703,
      35.7714620461596
    ],
    [
      51.388017273080685,
      35.772193283392454
    ],
    [
      51.388725376260794,
      35.77338586057598
    ],
    [
      51.38959449580085,
      35.774717661171216
    ],
    [
      51.39010939611279,
      35.7754923166625
    ],
    [
      51.39056009104643,
      35.77615381646097
    ],
    [
      51.391750991849335,
      35.77794695700689
    ],
    [
      51.3925126553907,
      35.77918295244885
    ],
    [
      51.39300618184956,
      35.78017511832749
    ],
    [
      51.3931349278823,
      35.7811587346649
    ],
    [
      51.3931349278823,
      35.782011677131834
    ],
    [
      51.39296326650532,
      35.78290812167626
    ],
    [
      51.392115688456414,
      35.78668542634139
    ],
    [
      51.39186892522699,
      35.788199868606796
    ],
    [
      51.39186892522699,
      35.78861753884191
    ],
    [
      51.39194402707943,
      35.78910494651146
    ],
    [
      51.392230688167956,
      35.78941935169951
    ],
    [
      51.39282747967391,
      35.79008294697373
    ],
    [
      51.39326736195243,
      35.79044621865728
    ],
    [
      51.39373272521663,
      35.790748637723794
    ],
    [
      51.39462321860981,
      35.79104451890581
    ],
    [
      51.39596164090855,
      35.791440563830776
    ],
    [
      51.39750927551051,
      35.79185395929528
    ],
    [
      51.39920174939931,
      35.79234564173544
    ],
    [
      51.401124893263436,
      35.79323764387117
    ],
    [
      51.401865182951724,
      35.79355095941179
    ],
    [
      51.402605472640005,
      35.7936640312856
    ],
    [
      51.40314199826213,
      35.79363796356674
    ],
    [
      51.403549694032506,
      35.79351617451363
    ],
    [
      51.40457957847542,
      35.7929939819459
    ],
    [
      51.40594214065532,
      35.79205403532404
    ],
    [
      51.40700429542545,
      35.791749436962704
    ],
    [
      51.40783049962127,
      35.79171465206454
    ],
    [
      51.409270762043576,
      35.79179302285922
    ],
    [
      51.4106547818956,
      35.791758154142
    ],
    [
      51.41294538839486,
      35.79137099403442
    ],
    [
      51.41652881963958,
      35.79059633854314
    ],
    [
      51.4182561622456,
      35.79002192671865
    ],
    [
      51.419618724425476,
      35.789273590403326
    ],
    [
      51.42018198831874,
      35.78859038147564
    ],
    [
      51.42065942152351,
      35.78791588972726
    ],
    [
      51.42104565962174,
      35.78708038161892
    ],
    [
      51.42166256769531,
      35.78577054161002
    ],
    [
      51.42258524759665,
      35.784569498704286
    ],
    [
      51.424201529985595,
      35.7830384602706
    ],
    [
      51.42424821718626,
      35.782994120002826
    ],
    [
      51.4257073388907,
      35.78137523922388
    ],
    [
      51.42670512064449,
      35.78006095680627
    ],
    [
      51.4275476695515,
      35.778700154826055
    ],
    [
      51.42929638601057,
      35.778851280540266
    ],
    [
      51.43052458628259,
      35.77918186280144
    ],
    [
      51.43168338439634,
      35.779894659847315
    ],
    [
      51.43320369399396,
      35.78094968999977
    ],
    [
      51.434167026125685,
      35.78200622889477
    ],
    [
      51.43451034887965,
      35.78241534958869
    ],
    [
      51.43493958614118,
      35.78276345002748
    ],
    [
      51.43586612171799,
      35.78340114522092
    ],
    [
      51.43671244248142,
      35.783834070519845
    ],
    [
      51.43718987568619,
      35.78401679600901
    ],
    [
      51.437650377446516,
      35.784114277542926
    ],
    [
      51.43935441836172,
      35.78459129165253
    ],
    [
      51.440974472607074,
      35.78491324055341
    ],
    [
      51.44240409001236,
      35.785274416761155
    ],
    [
      51.44655883177739,
      35.78642324041013
    ],
    [
      51.44986339710357,
      35.787711371289845
    ],
    [
      51.45414638198716,
      35.790021172347366
    ],
    [
      51.456953648998024,
      35.79145104120974
    ],
    [
      51.45848938129748,
      35.79260237942964
    ],
    [
      51.46048486098601,
      35.79319414179369
    ],
    [
      51.4631912937017,
      35.79280689786708
    ],
    [
      51.46631338499577,
      35.79189301896406
    ],
    [
      51.46968215570024,
      35.79137099403442
    ],
    [
      51.47176354989628,
      35.79070086087569
    ],
    [
      51.47392004594476,
      35.790230887564775
    ],
    [
      51.4755669222803,
      35.79008504244953
    ],
    [
      51.47634602018027,
      35.79011689368161
    ],
    [
      51.475195184874565,
      35.788893890189534
    ],
    [
      51.474001518043615,
      35.78769502657866
    ],
    [
      51.47337656334301,
      35.78710326421461
    ],
    [
      51.473164668830776,
      35.786918275611555
    ],
    [
      51.47271405771615,
      35.786696322815516
    ],
    [
      51.47197645023689,
      35.786498342262576
    ],
    [
      51.47143464401577,
      35.786372194619815
    ],
    [
      51.470898286031684,
      35.78625468033732
    ],
    [
      51.47047977760624,
      35.78605016189988
    ],
    [
      51.470093539507985,
      35.7853669529722
    ],
    [
      51.468210628779104,
      35.78154606241056
    ],
    [
      51.46661203220586,
      35.77806447128938
    ],
    [
      51.46429468743545,
      35.77534865084211
    ],
    [
      51.46226685360071,
      35.773120321883454
    ],
    [
      51.4601961882407,
      35.770726450337094
    ],
    [
      51.457868030815234,
      35.7679843945329
    ],
    [
      51.456591383142865,
      35.76649576852929
    ],
    [
      51.45604412868468,
      35.76584281827206
    ],
    [
      51.45545404270126,
      35.76389276849875
    ],
    [
      51.45466019265168,
      35.76165538708466
    ],
    [
      51.45437043025899,
      35.76105465608421
    ],
    [
      51.45382325961984,
      35.76041042300628
    ],
    [
      51.45252507045632,
      35.75474258008034
    ],
    [
      51.45226757839083,
      35.753575819158605
    ],
    [
      51.45126988045607,
      35.75290543454278
    ],
    [
      51.44961755588349,
      35.751895331391346
    ],
    [
      51.44899528339187,
      35.75162543410917
    ],
    [
      51.449166944768876,
      35.750301931598074
    ],
    [
      51.4494673521786,
      35.74830804447114
    ],
    [
      51.44947808101466,
      35.74777688326705
    ],
    [
      51.449360063818,
      35.74710633101316
    ],
    [
      51.44894163921157,
      35.746165965296115
    ],
    [
      51.44855548493237,
      35.74559121819553
    ],
    [
      51.44729744508504,
      35.743562378532374
    ],
    [
      51.447220834490054,
      35.743335564232495
    ],
    [
      51.44709896161791,
      35.74297455566281
    ],
    [
      51.446921935822864,
      35.741990520230246
    ],
    [
      51.44640494003514,
      35.742042739487005
    ],
    [
      51.44568619183801,
      35.742173329538446
    ],
    [
      51.44501019134705,
      35.742364939845
    ],
    [
      51.44450593605214,
      35.74251304807407
    ],
    [
      51.44359398498687,
      35.74261757040665
    ],
    [
      51.442885881806774,
      35.74260885322735
    ],
    [
      51.442124134446374,
      35.74257398451012
    ],
    [
      51.440976148987716,
      35.742582617870426
    ],
    [
      51.4400051893241,
      35.74266978966341
    ],
    [
      51.43922198429155,
      35.74266978966341
    ],
    [
      51.43831003322629,
      35.74269585738227
    ],
    [
      51.43709767475127,
      35.742687140202975
    ],
    [
      51.436325282373815,
      35.74260885322735
    ],
    [
      51.43569228104616,
      35.742495529896445
    ],
    [
      51.43511284007977,
      35.742364939845
    ],
    [
      51.43449056758817,
      35.7420863253835
    ],
    [
      51.43376109055498,
      35.74176412502552
    ],
    [
      51.43313873424435,
      35.741398338771035
    ],
    [
      51.432537919424874,
      35.74109357277163
    ],
    [
      51.432001477621775,
      35.74086717756691
    ],
    [
      51.43125045909741,
      35.7406146308243
    ],
    [
      51.43032777919609,
      35.74047532359356
    ],
    [
      51.428568250081895,
      35.74044917205566
    ],
    [
      51.4245771230668,
      35.74028379710606
    ],
    [
      51.422999732708575,
      35.7402472520082
    ],
    [
      51.42043579234684,
      35.74018799195278
    ],
    [
      51.41870844974082,
      35.740153039416526
    ],
    [
      51.41754973544612,
      35.7400834696202
    ],
    [
      51.4168738187742,
      35.74024012739051
    ],
    [
      51.416165799413136,
      35.740527542850344
    ],
    [
      51.415403968233704,
      35.740980333259756
    ],
    [
      51.4137785495703,
      35.74212119410072
    ],
    [
      51.41259837760347,
      35.74265235530481
    ],
    [
      51.41119298389836,
      35.74310514571425
    ],
    [
      51.40940118445695,
      35.743505716866906
    ],
    [
      51.40708375586754,
      35.74399337599354
    ],
    [
      51.40637833489646,
      35.74407602155884
    ],
    [
      51.40548247708528,
      35.74408918114682
    ],
    [
      51.404372042552865,
      35.7440194437124
    ],
    [
      51.40323478593026,
      35.74384099299385
    ],
    [
      51.40175429037273,
      35.74333154091897
    ],
    [
      51.400820881635326,
      35.742826531252774
    ],
    [
      51.40001613511163,
      35.74234323071578
    ],
    [
      51.39903444661195,
      35.74181206951167
    ],
    [
      51.39844436062853,
      35.74160738343616
    ],
    [
      51.39739838293153,
      35.7413417609246
    ],
    [
      51.39660436524389,
      35.74122852141272
    ],
    [
      51.39584798230151,
      35.74120245369386
    ],
    [
      51.395139879121416,
      35.741263390129944
    ],
    [
      51.39391142739231,
      35.74147679338472
    ],
    [
      51.3929780186549,
      35.741772842204824
    ],
    [
      51.39210361851585,
      35.74206897484393
    ],
    [
      51.39070618761875,
      35.74261757040665
    ],
    [
      51.38982642306166,
      35.74293532835594
    ],
    [
      51.389268523586416,
      35.74310514571425
    ],
    [
      51.38880718363578,
      35.74324889535367
    ],
    [
      51.388526892793635,
      35.743303293905285
    ],
    [
      51.38771158507194,
      35.7434077324188
    ],
    [
      51.38697657598266,
      35.7434491390205
    ],
    [
      51.38647508671579,
      35.743414270303276
    ],
    [
      51.38534319451125,
      35.74325752871394
    ],
    [
      51.38412002338114,
      35.74300506579035
    ]
  ];
}
```